# What is correct syntax for dvm inside when clause in xsl transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, soa, bpel

I'm struggling to manage a DVM inside a when clause in XSLT transformation file:

```
<xsl:for-each >
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test='dvm:lookupValue("mapping.dvm","MansioneId",bpws:getVariableData("/ns1:EBM_PersonnelInfo/ns1:Employee/ns1:Role/ns2:Job/ns2:JobID"),"Flag","0") = "Y"'>
```

Bpel fails with this error:

```
<bpelFault><faultType>0</faultType><subLanguageExecutionFault xmlns="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension"><part name="summary"><summary>XPath expression failed to execute. An error occurs while processing the XPath expression; the expression is ora:doXSLTransformForDoc('xsl/Transformation.xsl', $inputVariable.payload). The XPath expression failed to execute; the reason was: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: oramds:/deployed-composites/default/PersonnelInfo4.9/xsl/Transformation.xsl&lt;Line 161, Column 28>: XML-22015: (Error) Function 'getVariableData' not found.. Check the detailed root cause described in the exception message text and verify that the XPath query is correct. </summary></part><part name="code"><code>XPathExecutionError</code></part></subLanguageExecutionFault></bpelFault>
```

Is the `getVariableData` function not supported?

Comment: What is DVM? What is `bpws`? What API are you trying to call?

Comment: DVM is Domain-value mapping and takes as input the "bpws:getVariableData" value which is taken from the input payload of my SOA composite.

Comment: It says: Function 'getVariableData' not found.
When I do a search for that function I see examples where it needs 2 arguments: see: https://blog.darwin-it.nl/2019/03/soasuite-12c-upgrade-composite-dvms.html. 
Could that be the reason?